# How to open Manage apps battery usage settings in MIUI devices

Tags: android, miui, xiaomi

How to open Manage apps battery usage settings in MIUI devices programmatically?

I open the settings by this:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

But I don't know how to open Manage apps battery usage settings in MIUI devices.

Comment: Did you try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999833/how-to-open-battery-use-in-about-device-part-of-settings-programatically-in-andr

Comment: I not try to open settings Or Info i wanna to open Manage apps battery usage settings in MIUI devices?

Comment: Hi @Boris Treukhov and Lila saad have you checked my answer below?

Comment: I have tested it but MIUI has custom power manager anyway.

Comment: could you share a screenshot of MIUI custom power manager. I am having MIUI device with Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 5):

You can try few methods below:

Personally  i don't have 5.1 devices but tried it over simulator

```
    Intent batterySaver = new Intent();
    battSaverIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$BatterySaverSettingsActivity"));
    startActivityForResult(batterySaver, 0);
```

or for summary usage

```
Intent batterySaver = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY);
startActivity(batterySaver);
```

Documentation link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS)

For API level >22

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS), 0);
```